# count how many columns would return if we search based on series genre

Tags: mysql

I've been through other questions with similar titles, but couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code

So here is simple MySQL code:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS sum FROM series WHERE id IN (SELECT s_id FROM s_genre WHERE g_id IN (1,5,19) GROUP BY s_id HAVING COUNT(s_id)>=3) AND stype=0 LIMIT 1
```

Well, it's used to count how many columns would return if we search based on series genre. The inner code would return 183 records in less than a sec, but when I run the whole code, it'd return internal error 500 after about a minute. Also ***series*** table contains about 5000 records. ***s_genre*** table contains about 25000 records. So what do you think the problem is?

Comment: It most likely timed out, have you tried running the whole mysql query in a sql shell to see how long that takes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS sum
FROM series
WHERE id IN (SELECT s_id
             FROM s_genre
             WHERE g_id IN (1, 5, 19)
             GROUP BY s_id
             HAVING COUNT(s_id) >= 3
            ) AND
      stype = 0
LIMIT 1;
```

Try re-phrasing it as a `join`.  These are often optimized more efficiently:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.id) AS sum
FROM series s JOIN
     (SELECT s_id
      FROM s_genre
      WHERE g_id IN (1, 5, 19)
      GROUP BY s_id
      HAVING COUNT(s_id) >= 3
     ) g
     on s.id = g.s_id
WHERE stype = 0;
```

As a note, the `limit` does nothing because an aggregation query with no `group by` only returns one row.

If the above doesn't improve performance, then create an index on `s_genre(s_id, g_id)` and write the query using `exists`:

```
select count(s.id)
from series s
where s.stype = 0 and
      exists (select 1 from s_genre g where s.id = g.sid and g.g_id = 1) AND
      exists (select 1 from s_genre g where s.id = g.sid and g.g_id = 5) AND
      exists (select 1 from s_genre g where s.id = g.sid and g.g_id = 19);
```